# How to pass and retrieve constant json data to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

[image]

I have lambda function defined sth like :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

   #get constant json argument passed from cloudwatch event rule

   ...
```

What is the way to get the values defined in Target/Configure Input /Constant(Json text).

Comment: Have your tried entering JSON text in the text field?

Comment: @Leon yes , but the question is how do I retrieve it ? should I change `def  lambda_handler(event, context):` ?

Comment: `print(event)` and check the lambda log in CloudWatch

Comment: have done that already it does not get the additional data passed :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As I read in AWS documents, json passed to python as dict type. And then I simply call the value like this:

passed json:

```
{"type": "daily", "retention": 7}
```

Then in your handler:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    type = event["type"]
    rententionDay = event["retention"]
    ...
```

Use this I was able to make an automation snapshot for all ebs volumes.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on NodeJS, but it should be the same for Python. The Constant under Input is a simple JSON encoded object, which can then be accessed using the event variable.

Input

```
{ "config": "uk" }
```

Lambda

```
console.log(event.config)
```

---

Found this entry as one of the top Google results, so hopefully this will help someone else.